# Hiding the password field during user registration?

Tags: 8

When I deselect the *Require email verification when a visitor creates an account* option, users must enter a password during registration. I want users to be able to register without a password, and also not receive a new signup email. When users create an account, they should be able to immediately log in, which means I can't use the blocked state for the user. I added a new field for "true confirmation", after they click on the link in my own custom email.

An even better solution would be if I could use Drupal's login method, but the users should still be able to log in, even when they aren't confirmed. Is there anything that does this already?

Comment: This might be close to what you want to do https://www.drupal.org/project/passwordless.  Either way I think your question is too broad and you should narrow it down to something that you have tried that perhaps it is missing something specific.

Comment: If you hide the password field for the registration form, what would users use to log in? The username is not sufficient, without a way to know it's the same person that created the account who is trying to log in.

Comment: I send the confirmation email in another way.